# Refreshing captcha submits the form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, captcha

When I try to refresh the captcha, it submits the form. I am wondering why? After refresh it posts the data to database and added an empty comment to it. There is nothing that seems to be submitting the form to me just wondering.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(); captcha.reset(true)">

    <h2 *ngIf="!parent.replying">Leave a Comment</h2>
    <h2 *ngIf="parent.replying">Leave a Reply</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message here" [(ngModel)]="comment.message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name (Optional)" [(ngModel)]="comment.name" title="Anonymous by default">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail (Optional)" [(ngModel)]="comment.email">
    </div>

    <math-captcha #captcha></math-captcha>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Post this comment</button>
        <button *ngIf="parent.replying" type="button" (click)="parent.replying=false" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Captcha component is-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'math-captcha',
    template: `
        Give an answer: {{ number1 | in_word }} {{ operation | to_str }} {{ number2 | in_word }} = 

        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="answer" 
            id="answer"
            class="btn btn-default" 
            title="Prove you are human by answering to this math question" 
            placeholder=" ? " 
            [(ngModel)]="user_input" 
            pattern="{{ answer }}"
            size="2" 
            required
        >
        <button 
            (click)="refresh()" 
            class="btn btn-link"
            title="Get Another Math Question"
        ><span 
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" 
                aria-hidden="true"
            ></span> Refresh</button>

    `
})
export class MathCaptchaComponent implements OnInit {
    user_input: string;
    number1: number;
    number2: number;
    operation: string;
    answer: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.number1 = this.random_number();
        this.number2 = this.random_number();
        this.operation = '+'; // for now, only + operation is used
        this.answer = this.number1 + this.number2 + ''; // empty string used to convert number to string
    }

    reset() {
        this.user_input = '';
        this.refresh();
    }

    random_number() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // multiplication factor 10 is used to get single digit
    }

    refresh() {
        alert("fffff");
        this.ngOnInit();
    }
}
```

I can prbably get away with it by changing the submit type of form, but not sure if that will work. Even if it does, why the form above is behaving so weirdly?

Comment: try using <button type="button"> in your captcha

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo . It works !. I would like know the reason why it was behaving like this earlier?

Comment: in a form, a button will be a "submit button" by defect. It's a common error to have a cancel button in a form and forget the "type" :)